# How to recreate this cut out words effect

Tags: effects

How can I "physically" cut out a word like this with a picture for the background on say a C.D cover? Does it require a special tool?

I mean words that are cut out into foreground  of a photo:

[image]

Comment: Physically? Or just make it seem like it's cut out but not actually? On what platform? What have you tried? What resources have you looked at? Lots lacking from this question

Comment: In the example, the word is actually physically cut out. Note how the shadows differ between the two cases.

Comment: Yes, Physically cut a word with a desired font. Does that require a special print shop?

Comment: @lorincurley Yes, it requires a special print shop

Comment: @lorincurley Hey, yes this is what's called a die-cut. You should ask your printer if they provide this service. Not all printers do, they sometimes outsource specialized tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You define the shape which you want to have cut out as a vector shape, and tell your print shop that you want that cut out.

They send your vector path out to a die-maker (you'll need to pay for this, probably in advance) to have a die made.

They'll then use the die on the printed piece.

Answer (score 0):

You can use photoshop,

In Photoshop just double click on layer > blending option > bevel and emboss.

It will depend on your creativity mind. This will also help you -

http://design.tutsplus.com/articles/the-comprehensive-guide-to-bevel-and-emboss--psd-17308

[image]

Comment: Not quite what the OP has in mind. They want to actually cut out the shapes of the letters, not simply make it look like they are.